# SeldonIO | sklearn_iris and sklearn_spacy_text | not working in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, istio, seldon

Ref:
https://github.com/SeldonIO/seldon-core/blob/master/examples/models/sklearn_iris/sklearn_iris.ipynb
https://github.com/SeldonIO/seldon-core/tree/master/examples/models/sklearn_spacy_text

#Steps Done

```
1. kubectl port-forward $(kubectl get pods -l istio=ingressgateway -n istio-system -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') -n istio-system 8003:80
2.kubectl create namespace john
3.kubectl config set-context $(kubectl config current-context) --namespace=john
4.kubectl create -f sklearn_iris_deployment.yaml
```

```
cat sklearn_iris_deployment.yaml
apiVersion: machinelearning.seldon.io/v1alpha2
kind: SeldonDeployment
metadata:
  name: seldon-deployment-example
  namespace: john
spec:
  name: sklearn-iris-deployment
  predictors:
  - componentSpecs:
    - spec:
        containers:
        - image: seldonio/sklearn-iris:0.1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: sklearn-iris-classifier
    graph:
      children: []
      endpoint:
        type: REST
      name: sklearn-iris-classifier
      type: MODEL
    name: sklearn-iris-predictor
    replicas: 1
```

kubectl get sdep -n john seldon-deployment-example -o json | jq .status

```
  "deploymentStatus": {
    "sklearn-iris-deployment-sklearn-iris-predictor-0e43a2c": {
      "availableReplicas": 1,
      "replicas": 1
    }
  },
  "serviceStatus": {
    "seldon-635d389a05411932517447289ce51cde": {
      "httpEndpoint": "seldon-635d389a05411932517447289ce51cde.john:9000",
      "svcName": "seldon-635d389a05411932517447289ce51cde"
    },
    "seldon-bb8b177b8ec556810898594b27b5ec16": {
      "grpcEndpoint": "seldon-bb8b177b8ec556810898594b27b5ec16.john:5001",
      "httpEndpoint": "seldon-bb8b177b8ec556810898594b27b5ec16.john:8000",
      "svcName": "seldon-bb8b177b8ec556810898594b27b5ec16"
    }
  },
  "state": "Available"
}
```

5.here iam using istio and as per this doc https://docs.seldon.io/projects/seldon-core/en/v1.1.0/workflow/serving.html i did the same

```
Istio
Istio REST
Assuming the istio gateway is at <istioGateway> and with a Seldon deployment name <deploymentName> in namespace <namespace>:

A REST endpoint will be exposed at : http://<istioGateway>/seldon/<namespace>/<deploymentName>/api/v1.0/predictions
```

6. 

curl  -s http://localhost:8003/seldon/john/sklearn-iris-deployment-sklearn-iris-predictor-0e43a2c/api/v0.1/predictions -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"data":{"ndarray":[[5.964,4.006,2.081,1.031]]}}' -v

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8003 (#0)
> POST /seldon/johnson-az-videspan/sklearn-iris-deployment-sklearn-iris-predictor-0e43a2c/api/v0.1/predictions HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8003
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 48
> 
* upload completely sent off: 48 out of 48 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< location: https://localhost:8003/seldon/john/sklearn-iris-deployment-sklearn-iris-predictor-0e43a2c/api/v0.1/predictions
< date: Fri, 23 Oct 2020 13:09:46 GMT
< server: istio-envoy
< connection: close
< content-length: 0
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

the same thing happen in **sklearn_spacy_text** model too but i wonder the same models working perfectly while running it on docker.

please find the sample responce from docker

```
curl  -s http://localhost:5000/predict -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"data":{"ndarray":[[5.964,4.006,2.081,1.031]]}}' -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> POST /predict HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 48
> 
* upload completely sent off: 48 out of 48 bytes
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 125
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Server: Werkzeug/1.0.0 Python/3.7.4
< Date: Fri, 23 Oct 2020 11:18:31 GMT
< 
{"data":{"names":["t:0","t:1","t:2"],"ndarray":[[0.9548873249364169,0.04505474761561406,5.7927447968952436e-05]]},"meta":{}}
* Closing connection 0
```

```
curl  -s http://localhost:5001/predict -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"data": {"names": ["text"], "ndarray": ["Hello world this is a test"]}}'
{"data":{"names":["t:0","t:1"],"ndarray":[[0.6811839197596743,0.3188160802403257]]},"meta":{}}
```

can any one help to resolve this issue

Comment: It appears that the request you make incorrectly tries to re-direct to an https protocol (port 443), Could you show how did you configure your istio gateway? 
Here is an [example](https://github.com/SeldonIO/seldon-core/blob/master/notebooks/istio_example.ipynb) of how this should be configured for http. Could you try with that and let me know if that works?

Comment: @Jakub yes you are right it works with https.. Thanks man for your responce. 
i have an anothe issue have installed seldon-core-analytics through helm
```
helm install seldon-core-analytics seldon-core-analytics \
   --repo https://storage.googleapis.com/seldon-charts \
   --namespace seldon-system
```
issue is prediction-analytics dashboard not showing any metrics

Comment: Hi @Antony Johnson, I have made an answer from above comment, If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted or upvote it as per [stackoverflow rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). About the second issue, please follow stackoverflow rule [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) and create new question for your new issue, kubernetes-helm tag might help be helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

### Issue

It appears that the request you make incorrectly tries to re-direct to an https protocol (port 443)

### Solution

**Use** https instead of http

```
curl -s https://localhost:8003/seldon/john/sklearn-iris-deployment-sklearn-iris-predictor-0e43a2c/api/v0.1/predictions -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"data":{"ndarray":[[5.964,4.006,2.081,1.031]]}}' -v
```

---

**Use** curl with -L flag, which instructs curl to follow redirects. In this case, the server returned a redirect response (301 Moved Permanently) for the HTTP request to `http://localhost:8003`. The redirect response instructs the client to send an additional request, this time using HTTPS, to `https://localhost:8003`.

More about it [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).